# How is "métis" pronounced?

Tags: prononciation

The sources I consulted ([HowJsay](http://www.forvo.com/word/m%C3%A9tis/#fr), [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/m%C3%A9tis/#fr), [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/metis)) say the “s” is not silent. So it may be an exception from the rule, such as “autobus”, “tennis”. Can you confirm that?

The reason I ask is because in Canadian English the “s” is silent and as a borrowing from French, that would be strange.

Comment: Guess I was wrong then! Wiktionary, thou hast failed me.

Comment: This is a weird question. You don't believe the dictionary but you believe anonymous internet strangers?

Comment: @Evpok La réponse sur la prononciation en anglais « _may-chif_ » ressemblait en fait à la prononciation française du mot [_métchif_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tchif), la langue mixte dont on parlait. Le lien c'est que le mot est basé sur l'ancien adjectif, qu'a utilisé Chateaubriand, [_métif_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9tif). L'article W. dit ensuite : « En français du Québec, le /t/ devant /i/, /y/, /j/, /ɥ/ est régulièrement affriqué en [ts], rarement en [tʃ] (_métsif_ ou _métchif_) » (Wikipédia). Pas exactement une réponse mais comme un éclairage intéressant... Merci.

Answer (score 9):

I confirm the **s** is not silent, like in **tennis**.

Comment: It's pronounced `may-tiss`.

Answer (score 5):

In the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA):

```
/me.tis/
```

Like you would pronounce the verb *“tisser”* at the first person singular: *“tisse”*.